# Appium - Finding mobile selectors from iOS app with Mac but without installing Xcode

Tags: appium, appium-ios, appium-desktop

Is this possible? I need to find mobile selectors from an iOS app to automate tests using Appium.

I have windows so I set up a virtual machine with MacOS High Sierra. I don't have enough disk space to install Xcode there, so I was thinking if there was an alternative way to get the selectors.

Maybe an emulator that I can set up with Appium inspector or something similar? that doesn't involve installing Xcode.

Comment: It's not possible without XCode as Appium communicate with iOS app via XCode command line tool and WebDriverAgent which is also an XCode project which has to be deployed on the device. Let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: I had to install Xcode but could grab the mobile elements with Appium Studio. Thanks.